# Is "One of the most important" (without a noun) still grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality, nouns, adjectives

When I was reading an article in a medical magazine of the George Washington University, I ran across a sentence in the article that:

"Brugmann says her relationship with Moody is one of the most important in her career."

As far as I know, "one of the" should be followed by a noun or a phrasal noun, so the above sentence would be written as " ... is one of the most **importance** in her career", or "... is one of the most **important things** in her career". I think that "one of the most important" is still incomplete, but a writer of a prestige university magazine hardly makes a basic grammatical error like that. I don't know the structure "one of the + an adjective" (without a noun) is still grammatical or not. 
I hope everyone can explain to me. Thank you!

Comment: It's perfectly fine as originally quoted.

Comment: The non-compartmentalized might prefer "of her career".

Comment: See the complete sentence. Better still, the whole broader context. The fragment is grammatically correct in that it references back to something said earlier.

Comment: The noun being referred to is *her relationship with Moody*. (*The most important relationship in Burgmann's career was the one she had with Moody.*)

Answer (score 1):

The quote implies, "...one of the most important (ones/relationships) in her career"

### Why?

If a noun can be understood from context, it can be omitted if used in a later reference if modified by a comparative or superlative adjective: https://eslbase.com/grammar/comparative-superlative

Comment: How and why? How do we know?

Comment: If a noun can be understood from context, it can be omitted if used in a later reference if modified by a comparative or superlative adjective: https://www.eslbase.com/grammar/comparative-superlative

Comment: That is the thing that ought to go into the answer.